# How to make driver.findelement as generic for Different locators in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to make locators are generic in `driver.findElement(####)`. It means I can use different locators like `By.Id` or `By.Name` or `By.Xpath` etc... to locate specific element.

How do I make this one as generic statement?

Comment: You don't actually need all these "finders"... you can use only `By.Xpath`. For example, if you have element's `id` or `name` you can find element by `xpath` - `'//element[@id="element's id"]'` or `'//element[@name="element's name"]'`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am repeating question, Might be i confused you. In my application during releases, I'm forced to change id to xpath or class name or tag. So I can't use any of the element selection methods like driver.findElement(By.id()).
In the next build I might have to use driver.findElement(By.xpath()) OR driver.findElement(By.name()) for the same element location. This means I will have to visit each and every class file I have written and modify By.id() to the respective selector.
Is there any way to avoid this by parametrising or some other way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I read the comment underneath your question and think I know what you're trying to achieve as I have done something similar for my project in C#. Our system is tested over multiple branches and on these branches we have sections that need varying element locators, on one branch, we use an XPath, on another we use a class selector, you get the idea.

To prevent the issue you described of having to go through the entire project and replace all of these selectors when changing branch/releasing I moved all the selectors to a series of classes. Here is an example:

Suppose I want to click on a back button. On branch `A`, this button is located by `By.Id("My-Back-Button")`. On Branch `B`, this button is located by `By.CssSelector(".take.me.back")`.

To begin with, I would create an abstract class called `Selectors` which would define an abstract method called something like `public By BackButton()`. I would then create 2 child classes of `Selectors`, `BranchA` and `BranchB` which would override the method `BackButton`:

```
// Within BranchA : Selectors
@override
public By BackButton() { return By.Id("My-Back-Button"); }

// Within BranchB : Selectors
@override
public By BackButton() { return By.CssSelector(".take.me.back"); }
```

The final step would be to have a factory class that would determine which branch you need. In my solution I have an XML config file which is read by this factory class to determine which class to use, but a static bool may be enough in your case.

This factory class, `SelectorFactory` would have a method named `public Selectors Get()` that would use some case/switch/if to create a new instance of the needed sub-class to `Selector`.

The final solution would be the following:

```
// During development
Driver.FindElement(SelectorFactory.Get().BackButton()).Click();
// Clicks By.Id("My-Back-Button");

// During release
Driver.FindElement(SelectorFactory.Get().BackButton()).Click();
// Clicks By.CssSelector(".take.me.back");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am not sure about C# code.Please provide same solution in Java. Thanks In Advance.